# Why kde keep asking password when i use chrome even if the password is not saved?

Tags: password, chromium

I have not saved the password of a website, but kde keep asking me that password and I find this annoying. :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using Chromium, Chromium will use the system's password manager instead of its own password manager. Therefore, it will try to open that password manager and read any passwords for websites.